# XML Parsing Error in Window Phone

Tags: silverlight, linq, windows-phone-7, xmlhttprequest, xml-parsing

I'm creating a tweeter example in window phone and got `NullReferenceException`

I think it might be that the syntax is incorrect on the right side of the expression but couldn't tell what and why..

Anyone has an idea why this resulted in error?

**.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        string url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=noradio";

        WebClient twitter = new WebClient();
        twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(twitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
        twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    }

    void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

        listBox1.ItemsSource = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("Status")

        select new TweeterItem
        {
            ImageSource = tweet.Element("user").Element("profile_image_url").Value,
            Message = tweet.Element("text").Value,
            UserName = tweet.Element("user").Element("screen_name").Value,
        };
    }
```

**.xaml:**

```
<ListBox Height="521" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,131,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="476">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="73" Width="73" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0"/>
<StackPanel Width="370">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="28" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
</StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Can you include the stack trace where the exception occurs in your post? My gamble is that somewhere in your dotted chains of properties there is a null object.

Comment: You're right and here is the exception detail:

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=NullReferenceException
  StackTrace:
       at XmlApp.MainPage.twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
       at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)
       at

Comment: I got this more descriptive error message.  You think some references are missing? 
data.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<TResult>.Current 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<XmlApp.TweeterItem>' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<XmlApp.TweeterItem>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Really dangerous to parse xml like this, because you don't test if element exist before accessing it. In your case it seems that you are accessing an xml element that does not exist. You should use a basic foreach to retreive wich xml element is missing.

Comment: I'm new to this.  Can you give me an example of the retrieving using foreach?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this, then I can check the values for null afterwards:

```
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(e.Result as Stream);
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                switch (xmlReader.Name)
                {
                    case "profile_image_url":
                        ImageSource = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml();
                        break;
                    case "text":
                        Message = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml();
                        break;
                    case "screen_name":
                        UserName = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```